# How can we check that how many times a java program has executed previously?

Tags: java

```
class Testing{

    static int count = 0;
    public Testing(){
        count++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Testing[] testObjects= new Testing[20];
        for(int i = 1; i<20;i++){
            if(Testing.count==5){
                System.out.println("5 objects are created.. Can't create anymore, although 20 objects can be stored");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else{
                    testObjects[i] = new Testing();
                    System.out.println("Object "+Testing.count+" is created.");
            }
        } // for loop close
        System.out.println("Program will exit");
    }
}
```

I have tried this code but it only keeps the information of a single run and I need to track the multiple execution

Comment: Create a loop that allows your program to run multiple times. If the program actually ends (process dies out), there's no where to store that info unless you wrote it to your drive via file or something similar. Thats why you must simulate the program restarting by looping it, and considering each loop iteration 1 execution.

Comment: What are you trying to count? How many have been initialized?

Comment: What are you trying to track? Once the program has completed running, it's out of memory and anything allocated within is gone. You would need some persistence mechanism (save a log file, serialize objects you care about, etc.)

Comment: How can I save info into a log file from the java program, please can you elaborate

Answer (score 3):

Declaring `count` as `static` binds that variable not to a class instance, but to the class itself. Therefore, all objects share a single `count` variable. The way you have your code set up, where you increment `count` in each constructor call, keeps track of how many `Testing` objects have been created throughout the lifetime of *this program*. If you want to persist data, you'll need to look at the [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class. Essentially, at the end of your program you'd put the value into storage:

```
myPreferences.put("ObjectsCreated", Testing.count);
```

Then retireve it later with

```
int previous = myPreferences.getInt("ObjectsCreated", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to persist the value of *count*, for example to a file.